# How to get the frequency plot of samples in an array matlab

Tags: matlab, discrete-signals

I have an array with 2 columns, the time index and the samples, What I first did was to segregate the samples since those are the only values I need but I am lost on what my next step will be to produce the frequency plot.

Comment: Please define what exactly you mean by "frequency plot". Power spectrum? Magnitude Spectrum? Phase Spectrum ? Phase delay or group delay ? All of these (and many more) are functions of frequency can generate a "frequency plot".

Comment: Magnitude spectrum, apologies for the confusion

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to get the frequency (magnitude) plot of your data would be something in the following lines

```matlab
%% Here I assume your data are stored in 'data'
% Get the time and sample values
t = data(:, 1); % Time vector
x = data(:, 2); % Sample values vector

% Create a couple of variables
Ts = t(2) - t(1); % Calculate the sampling period
fs = 1/Ts; % Calculate the sampling frequency
fVec = linspace(0, fs, length(t)); % Create the frequency vector

% Calculate the frequency representation of the signal Vector
X = fft(x);

% Plot the magnitude spectrum (some alternatives)
figure(1)
subplot(3, 1, 1) % Plot full vector in linear frequency axis
plot(fVec, abs(X)); grid on;
xlabel("Frequency (Hz)", "FontSize", 14)
ylabel("Amplitude (a.u.)", "FontSize", 14)
title("2-Sided Magnitude - Linear Frequency Axis", "FontSize", 18)

subplot(3, 1, 2) % Plot single sided spectrum in linear frequency axis
plot(fVec(1:floor(end/2)), abs(X(1:floor(end/2)))); grid on;
xlabel("Frequency (Hz)", "FontSize", 14)
ylabel("Amplitude (a.u.)", "FontSize", 14)
title("One-Sided Magnitude - Linear Frequency Axis", "FontSize", 18)

subplot(3, 1, 3) % Plot single sided spectrum in logarithmic frequency axis
semilogx(fVec(2:floor(end/2)), abs(X(2:floor(end/2)))); grid on;
xlabel("Frequency (Hz)", "FontSize", 14)
ylabel("Amplitude (a.u.)", "FontSize", 14)
title("One-Sided Magnitude - Logarithmic Frequency Axis", "FontSize", 18)

%% ========= NOTES =========
% Please note that in the logarithmic-axis case we do not plot the DC. This is because, in the logarithmic axis, 0 value cannot be represented.
```

Some alternatives are presented in the code above, which of course you can combine and/or tailor to your needs.

Comment: Im having an error it says, variable "f" is not recognized as a variable, what should be the f here? Also in the "X" variable that used fft was not used in the later parts of the code, or did I miss something?

Comment: Hey @kapposki it was an error on my side... I am sorry for that. I didn't type the code in MatLab so I didn't get the errors. It should be fixed now. Let me know if there's more errors or if this worked for you.